# Is there any way to compare ZipArchive objects after close() has been called?

Tags: php

I stumbled on a surprisingly difficult issue while writing some unit tests.

### Simplified scenario:

1. Zip archive is created.
2. It is populated with `ZipArchive::addFromString()` method.
3. It is than closed.
4. Filename used in `ZipArchive::open()` is unknown.

### Code example

```
function zipUp() {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open(rand() . '.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'success');
    $zip->close();

    return $zip;
}

$zip1 = zipUp();
$zip2 = zipUp();

// TODO: Compare the archives
```

### The issue

Compare content of zip archives. Comparison method can use something similar to `ZipArchive::statIndex()`.

Ideally without any accessing the filesystem, reading zip data only from memory.

Comment: Try, `hash_file`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php   A lot of times, I use the file hash for the filename, and store the "users" filename in the DB.  Which avoids all kinds of issues.  Of course this is exact matching, if you want some other type of matching, you should define the criteria.

Comment: `Ideally without any accessing the filesystem, reading zip data only from memory`  As far as I know, once you close the file, it's no longer in memory.  That said there is no reason you can't re-open the file later.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It this particular case I do not know the filename of the archive (don't ask why), I have just an instance of the `ZipArchive`.

Comment: I would make a wrapper class of (or extend) ZipArchive that you can keep track of the filename in.  `class MyZipArchive extends ZipArchive{ public function open($filename, $flags=null){  $this->filename = $filename; parent::open($filename,$flags); }` then add  `public function getFilename(){ return $this->filename;}`  problem solved.

Comment: `$zip->filename`

Comment: @Sammitch I can't believe that it didn't occurred to me to look up public properties of in PHP docs... This is actually perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

> It this particular case I do not know the filename of the archive (don't ask why), I have just an instance of the ZipArchive

I would try something like this:

```
class MyZipArchive extends ZipArchive{

    protected $filename;

    #override open
    public function open($filename, $flags=null){
        #store the filename
        $this->filename = $filename;
        return parent::open($filename,$flags);
    }

    public function getFilename(){
        return $this->filename;
    }

    public function getFileHash(){
        return md5_file($this->filename);
    }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
function zipUp() {
    $zip = new MyZipArchive();
    $zip->open(rand() . '.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'success');
    $zip->close();

    return $zip;
}

$zip1 = zipUp();
$zip2 = zipUp();

if($zip1->getFileHash() == $zip2->getFileHash()){
       //do something
}
```